# one process multiple listening port VS multiple process each listening on one port

Tags: java, c++

I'm going to implement a server side program, and I'm curious if the following two implementations have the same effect:

1. one server process listening on 10 ports with 1000 threads
2. 10 server processes with each one having 100 threads and listening on 1 port

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 will use less memory, especially for java variant.
Stability of option 1 will be less, since one process is the one point of failure here - everything you do to crash process will affect the whole server.
Option 1 allows you to use in-memory interoperability between different connections (unless you make server cluster).
Restart and service management for option 1 is much easier.

Comment: Say, disregard threading and there are 10 sending clients. Will listening on 3 different ports received faster than when listening on 1 port only?

Comment: Ports are not network card abstraction, so it doesn't matter for physical layer how many ports you have. And in your program reading from ports is just reading/copying data in memory - data bandwidth, number of packets and processing time for each data packet matter much more than number of ports. Reading by 3 threads in parallel can be faster in proper environment, but only for extreme bandwidth. Number of ports start to give negative effects when you deal with few hundreds of them.